# What is the most efficient way to solve this system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

What is the best way to solve this system for $x$ and $y$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$ using the minimum amount of effort?

$$(s^2 - 4)y + x = \dfrac{1}{s+1} + s + 2 \\ 
(s^2 - 1)x + y = \dfrac{1}{s-2} + s - 1$$

Is using the determinant the best way to solve this?
I am interested more, in the steps rather than the result. Can you show me all the procedure?
We need the most simplified solution because in the end we want to find the inversed Laplace of x,y.
Thank you.

Comment: Standard "add multiple of one row to another" techniques only require a few steps...

Comment: You have two equations.  Are there two unknowns?  The equations involve three symbols, $x,y,s$, so the question is not entirely clear.

Comment: I had assumed that $s$ is just some constant given that the equations are linear in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Forgot to mention it, sEℝ.

Comment: @KenDuna if I do that, then the result would be a really huge fraction which I don't know how to simplify. That;s why I asked for the procedure

Comment: You need to clarify the question. What variables are you solving for?

Comment: Why do you need "the most efficient way" to solve just a couple of linear equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solving the second equation for $y$ we get:
$$y=-{\frac {{s}^{3}x-2\,{s}^{2}x-{s}^{2}-sx+3\,s+2\,x-3}{s-2}}$$ with $$s\ne 2$$ plugging this in the first equation we get
$$-{\frac { \left( {s}^{2}-4 \right)  \left( {s}^{3}x-2\,{s}^{2}x-{s}^{2
}-sx+3\,s+2\,x-3 \right) }{s-2}}+x= \left( s+1 \right) ^{-1}+s+2
$$
solving this for $x$ we obtain $$x=\frac{1}{s+1}$$ for $$s\ne -1$$
if we set this in one equation we get for $y$ $$y=\frac{1}{s-2}$$ for $$s\ne 2$$

Comment: why is x =1/(s+1)? when I try to solve it, I find that x = 1/(s+1) + (a non-zero fraction)..